# Unique function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I used unique (MATLAB function ) for  finding unique rows of the matrix.

The matrix constructed in a function and I use unique after that. But the answer is not true.

unique just change matrix rows. By format long in MATLAB, the rows are equal.

I really do not know what is the problem? Am I wrong?

I am grateful to you for your help.

---

**EDIT** From the comment on an answer:

Actaully my matrix is the vertices of the quadrilateral, that sometimes be a line. for example:

```
A=[0.3 0.4;0.3,0.4;0.4,0.3;0.4,0.3]
```

and by unique

```
A=[0.4,0.3;0.4,0.3;0.3,0.4,0.3,0.4]
```

but I need to

```
A=[0.4,0.3;0.3,0.4]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your input, expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your example, I get exactly what you would expect.

```
clear
A=[0.3 0.4;0.3,0.4;0.4,0.3;0.4,0.3];
A = unique(A,'rows')
```

Gives

```
A =

    0.3000    0.4000
    0.4000    0.3000
```

Either you call `unique` wrongly, or the rows are not exact duplicates.

To check for the latter, try calculating the difference between two 'equal' rows and see whether it returns zeros.

Comment: The difference between two 'equal' rows are about  1.0e-015,could  I use unique? how can I use unique with  a tolerance?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a floating point issue? If two numbers are very close, they may appear to be equal when you display them (with or without using `format long`) even though they are not actually equal. For example

```
>> X = [1, 1e-20, 1e-20; 1, 1e-20, 1e-21];
>> format long;
>> X
ans =
   1.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000
   1.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000
```

So the rows look equal. However, when you do

```
>> unique(X, 'rows')
ans =
   1.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000
   1.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000
```

You can see that they aren't equal.

Comment: Actaully my matrix is the vertices of the quadrilateral, that sometimes be a line. for example: A=[0.3 0.4;0.3,0.4;0.4,0.3;0.4,0.3] and by unique A=[0.4,0.3;0.4,0.3;0.3,0.4,0.3,0.4] but I need to A=[0.4,0.3;0.3,0.4]